# Choking voice or Choked voice

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, noun-phrases

If you feel Judith speak while weeping, we say:

1. I sensed Judith speak in a choked voice
2. I sensed Judith speak in a choking voice
3. I sensed Judith's choking voice
4. I sensed Judith's choked voice

Comment: Your examples have other issues, but regarding the title topic, use "choked voice". I don't think there is such a thing as a *choking voice*, though there could be a *choking sound* if someone was being choked.

Comment: "Choking voice" sounds like it might mean that her voice chokes other people.

Comment: **Sensed** is not the idiomatic verb. You *heard*.

Answer (score 1):

An idiomatic way to express this idea:

> Her voice sounded choked.

This statement implies that the speaker heard this quality in her voice when she spoke.

P.S. Or you could say:

> She sounded choked up.
>
> She was choked up.